# Prevent sequelize from returning timestamps during select and update

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

While using sequelize, how can I prevent sequelize from selecting the `createdAt`, `updatedAt` and `deletedAt` columns during `findAll` or any select/update queries?

Note: I do not want to disable the timestamps in the model using `timestamps: false`. The requirement is to inform sequelize not to select these timestamp columns during SELECT and UPDATE.

Also, there is `exclude` for `findAll` and `findOne`. But I would like to know whether there is a way to avoid this explicit mentioning of fields to exclude repeatedly and specify this somewhere globally (to a model).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the 'attributes' option, like this?

```
Model.findAll({
 attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'deletedAt'] }
});
```

in [docs](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel) i saw the returning option can return values if you using postgres.
[image]

Comment: Yes. This works for `findAll` and `findOne`. How can we do this in update with `returning: true`?